# JavaScript phone detection and redirection

Tags: javascript, html, detection

Hello i'm trying to detect when my website is used by some phone, and then redirect to mobile version: mobile.html, in javascript. I've tried different things, to make it work:

1.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.mobilecheck = function() {
    var check = false;
    (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})
    (navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'mobile.html');
    return check;
};
</script>
```

2.

```
    if( screen.width <= 480 ) {
    location.href = '/mobile.html';
    }
```

This is just some of the approaches i've tried.

What is it i'm doing wrong, when I try to access the website on my phone, it gives me the error 'Not found the requested URL /mobile.html was not found on this server.' I should mention that the webside is local.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: @LucasCosta: Assuming the page is on `domain.com`, the effects of those are **exactly** identical.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I've tried with the domain, then the domain appears 2 twice.

Comment: @Hansensert: That tells you you've forgotten to put the protocol on. But you don't need or want the domain if you're linking within a domain.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by the protocol?

Comment: @Hansensert: I should have said "scheme," not "protocol" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator

Comment: Do you know why it wont work on my first appraoch, whit the regex?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mobile.html is indeed in the same folder and has the proper permissions.
Depending on the web servers you're using you might want to try one of these options:

`location.href = './mobile.html';
 location.href = 'mobile.html';`

Answer (score 0):

If your mobile.html file is inside the same folder as your checking file(ex:index.html) 
You can use the below code:

```
 if( window.innerWidth <= 480 ) {
    location.href = 'mobile.html';
 }
```

Comment: yes i've allready did that and it solved the problem I also had another small poroblem but it work now, but why does it work with my second appraoch? with the regex?

Answer (score 0):

`/mobile.html` tells the browser to go to `http://example.com/mobile.html`, even on a page which has more to the path. That is, on `http://example.com/path/here/index.html`, `/mobile.html` goes to `http://example.com/mobile.html`. The error is telling you that there's nothing at `http://example.com/mobile.html`.

So either

- Put something at `http://example.com/mobile.html`, or
- Change the link to link to where `mobile.html` is. For instance, if it's right there next to `index.html` in my example above, then you want just `mobile.html` (no leading `/`)

Comment: Yes I found out that I had to move the / from the URL, what do you mean by a protocol?

Comment: And also it does not work with my first approach? only with the second.

Comment: @Hansensert: Re protocol, see my answer to your comment on the question.